# Swift's FileManager.default.url not creating files, keeps throwing errors

Tags: swift, persistence, nsfilemanager

I've written these two function

```
func locallySave(_ data: Data?, for utility: Utility) throws {
    var fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
                                               in: .userDomainMask,
                                               appropriateFor: nil,
                                               create: true)
    fileURL.appendPathComponent(Constants.appShortName)
    fileURL.appendPathComponent("\(utility).json")
    do {
        try data?.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        throw error
    }
}
```

and

```
func locallyLoad(_ utility: Utility) throws -> Data? {
    var fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
                                               in: .userDomainMask,
                                               appropriateFor: nil,
                                               create: false)
    fileURL.appendPathComponent(Constants.appShortName)
    fileURL.appendPathComponent("\(utility).json")
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return data
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        throw error
    }
}
```

I think I've got one of two potential bugs in these function.

The first is that I've set `create: true` in the save function which should make it so if there isn't any file/directory, it will create them.
The second is that it might be creating them, but whenever I run the app, the directory (in the simulator) seems to be changing so I don't know if it's ever going to pull the file if it is there.

For example if I run the app, it will say the URL is something like
`/Users/<MyUsername>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C78E5655-0A29-4FA6-9EC3-20317881C18F/data/Containers/Data/Application/17F82456-9C7A-4D67-988E-88843B3446D8/Library/Application Support/AppTemplate/<SomeUtility>.json`
but if I run the app again, I'll get something like
`/Users/<MyUsername>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C78E5655-0A29-4FA6-9EC3-20317881C18F/data/Containers/Data/Application/0397D6F1-94EC-4EF2-9F3C-68764109F845/Library/Application Support/AppTemplate/<SomeUtility>.json`
Notice how the second string of digits is completely different.

I don't think it's all the second error because where I go to the `fileURL` in finder, there's nothing there and it doesn't look like anything has been created at all.

The `fileURL` in both functions always comes out to be the same for both functions in the debugger. How do I get FileManager to create the file if it doesn't exist and how do I make sure it's always pulling from the same directory it will have saved to?

The error I get is `NSUnderlyingError=0x600000fb0480 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

Thanks

Comment: The problem is only because you never create the Constants.appShortName folder.

Comment: A quick fix is to comment/remove `fileURL.appendPathComponent(Constants.appShortName)` and read/write your file into the `.applicationSupportDirectory`. Otherwise, as mentioned, you need to create the directory `Constants.appShortName` first, then write your file into it, and then read the file content from it.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks, I didn't realize I'd need to make each folder separately. That's very helpful :)